# Python ingest pdf without using packages that require pip install

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, pdftotext

I am hoping to extract text from pdf files in Jupyter notebook. Unfortunately in my work place we cannot install any python packages using pip install or conda install. This includes most of the popular pdf-to-text packages I have seen referenced online: pypdf2, pdfminer, textract, pdftotext, tika, slate, pdfquery, xpdf, tabula, etc.

I am wondering if there is any other way to ingest a pdf file into a Jupyter notebook with one of the packages automatically included in Anaconda, short of converting the pdf to a text file before ingesting?